# Getting empty data when using $_POST to get data from post

Tags: php

I am getting empty strings I have an API not conned to any HTML document.

HERE IS SOME SAMPLE CODE

```
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $age = $_POST['age'];

      if (empty($name)) 
          echo "Please enter name";
      elseif(empty($age))
          echo "Please enter age";
      else
          echo "$name is $age years old.";
  }
```

Copied this from geeks for geeks but still getting empty
response is

```
echo "Please enter name";
```

Getting empty data when using $_POST to get data from post

If I am changing to GET is works

Comment: Ah, that last line: _"If I am changing to GET is works"_ is a big clue. Your form can either send it's content with the URL (GET) or as content (POST). You can select which one with [the method atttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method). So, try to add `method="post"` to the form tag.

Comment: I am assuming you mean changing `$_POST['name']` to `$_GET['name']`. Perhaps you meant changing `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"` to `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"`?

Comment: It rather sounds like it's the code that sends the request that should be fixed. If you mean that it works when using `$_GET`, then the request methods seem correct (the if-statements wouldn't even be executed otherwise), but that the data is send as query parameters (in the URL) instead of in the body (as application/x-www-form-urlencoded data)